# Keyboard problems with my W key

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, keyboard-layout, kvm-switch

My <kbd>W</kbd> key doesn't work correctly, for instance in order for it to work I have to press it multiple times and sometimes the key will work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you verify if it is physical problems by reconnecting the external keyboard(if external) to other computer and status of K key?

If not, you may also check the driver used for keyboard.

Comment: Any chance there might be some debris/gunk in the keyboard itself? Someone spilled a Red Bull on mine once and it caused all kinds of problems like this. Try removing the W key and cleaning it out with some rubbing alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use On-Screen keyboard in short `osk`.

To launch press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `osk`.

To type using keyboard combination you need to have knowledge of [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) to type

```
small w   : ALT+119
capital W : ALT+87
```

<kbd>ALT</kbd> is the key present on the `left side` and numbers like 119 and 87 you have to enter from your `number pad` so you have to turn on <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>.